# Why can I not return an array of objects in an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, javascript-objects

In node.js I am trying to get a list of bid and ask prices from a trade exchange website (within an async function). Within the foreach statement I can `console.info()` the object data(on each iteration) but when I put all of this into an array and then return it to another function it passes as 'undefined'.

```js
const symbolPrice = async() => {
    let symbolObj = {}
    let symbolList = []

  await bookTickers((error, ticker) => {
    ticker.forEach(symbol => {
      if (symbol.symbol.toUpperCase().startsWith(starts.toUpperCase())) {

        symbolObj = {
          symbol: symbol.symbol,
          bid: symbol.bidPrice,
          ask: symbol.askPrice
        }
        console.info(symbolObj);

      }

      symbolList.push(symbolObj)


    });

    const results = Promise.all(symbolList)
    return results;

  });

}

const symbolPriceTest = async() => {

  const res = await symbolPrice(null, 'ETH', true);
  console.log(res)

}
```

I have tried pretty much everything I can find on the internet like different awaits/Promise.all()'s. I do admit I am not as familiar with async coding as I would like to be.

Comment: There are lots of problems here and you don't show how `bookTickers()` works or what you're trying to do with the result you generate so we can't really offer a complete solution.  For starters, declare all your variables in the proper scope.  Don't reuse variable names in a loop. Only use `Promise.all()` with  an array of promises.  Only use `await` when you are awaiting a promise.  Don't mix promises and plain callbacks.

Comment: `bookTickers()` retrieves a current symbol bid and ask price through a WebSocket. With `ticker` being an array of objects(of the symbols and their bid/ask price).

Comment: Yo, hey you don't have to go off like that man listen I believe I have explained to the best of my ability what I am doing and what I am trying to achieve. bookTickers returns a promise or undefined.

Comment: Also I just want to add all of that data to an array and pass it on. Lets say to console.log() it to test functionality.

Answer (score 2):

So, if the basic problem here is to call `bookTickers()`, retrieve the asynchronous result from that call, process it and then get that processed result as the resolved value from calling `symbolPrice()`, then you can do that like this:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const bookTickersP = promisify(bookTickers);

async function symbolPrice(/* declare arguments here */) {
    let symbolList = [];

    const ticker = await bookTickersP(/* fill in arguments here */);
    for (let symbol of ticker) {
        if (symbol.symbol.toUpperCase().startsWith(starts.toUpperCase())) {
            symbolList.push({
                symbol: symbol.symbol,
                bid: symbol.bidPrice,
                ask: symbol.askPrice
            });
        }
    }
    return symbolList;
}

async function symbolPriceTest() {

  const res = await symbolPrice(null, 'ETH', true);
  console.log(res)

}
```

Things to learn from your original attempt:

1. Only use `await` when you are awaiting a promise.
2. Only use `Promise.all()` when you are passing it an array of promises (or an array of a mixture of values and promises).
3. Don't mix plain callback asynchronous functions with promises.  If you don't have a promise-returning version of your asynchronous function, then promisify it so you do (as shown in my code above with `bookTickersP()`.
4. Do not guess with `async` and `await` and just throw it somewhere hoping it will do something useful.  You MUST know that you're awaiting a promise that is connected to the result you're after.
5. Don't reuse variables in a loop.
6. Your original implementation of `symbolPrice()` had no return value at the top level of the function (the only return value was inside a callback so that just returns from the callback, not from the main function).  That's why `symbolPrice()` didn't return anything.  Now, because you were using an asynchronous callback, you couldn't actually  directly return the results anyway so other things had to be redone.

Comment: Ok I am going to be 100% honest I thought you just came in to berate me with no real teaching objective. Well played... thank you for your help and actually making this a teaching experience.

Comment: @DavidWilliams - Sometimes it's just really hard to understand the questions here and those of us trying to answer get a bit frustrated when we can't see enough info in the question to understand what you're trying to do.  I was just trying to get to the bottom of what you were trying to accomplish and how `bookTickers()` works.  I am sometimes very direct in my approach which isn't always perceived the way I want, but isn't meant to do anything more than try to get to the bottom of things.  Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Seems to me the original comment was blunt but not unkind.  I think I'd prefer a slightly different solution, though; one where the promisified bookTickersP is improved to return an array of `{ symbol, bid, ask }`, and the symbol list is created with a filter.

Comment: @danh - You're welcome to offer your own solution if you want to show something different.  I prefer to keep the promisifed versions true to the original API so `bookTickerP()` here resolves to an array of ticker symbol objects which is the same data that `bookTicker()` calls its callback with.   `.filter()` would certainly be appropriate - I just chose to not change that part of the logic.

Comment: I like the pure promise version, too. Just suggesting a layer in between that reshapes the data, separate from a layer that uses it.

Comment: I actually figured out what I was doing wrong and no longer needed the promisify. This blunt teaching lesson seemed to have worked out well! I no longer have to use promisify as I went into the actual node package itself for the module I was using and figured out how it works and what was needed to effectively use it. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Just a few thoughts on organization that might be reused in other contexts...

Promisify book tickers (with a library, or pure js using the following pattern).  This is just the api made modern:

```
async function bookTickersP() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bookTickers((error, ticker) => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(ticker);
    })
  });
}
```

Use that to shape data in the way that the app needs. This is your app's async model getter:

```
// resolves to [{ symbol, bid, ask }, ...]
async function getSymbols() {
  const result = await bookTickersP();
  return result.map(({ symbol, bidPrice, askPrice }) => {
    return { symbol: symbol.toUpperCase(), bid: bidPrice, ask: askPrice }
  });
}
```

Write business logic that does things with the model, like ask about particular symbols:

```
async function symbolPriceTest(search) {
  const prefix = search.toUpperCase();
  const symbols = await getSymbols();
  return symbols.filter(s => s.symbol.startsWith(prefix));
}

symbolPriceTest('ETH').then(console.log);
```